# N++ macro parameterization

Tags: xml, automation, macros, notepad++, parameterization

I am a new N++ user, and I have an XML file that I need to create 10 duplicates of and where it says

```
<CSPN>6000</CSPN>
```

I want to search anywhere it says 6000 and wherever it says 6000, I want to replace it with a unique 4 digit number. All 10 duplicate files will have a unique 4 digit number for this tag.

Comment: Do you want a "unique 4 digit number" for each matching tag in a single file?

Comment: The reason it is unique is because I want the data I changed in all the xmls to reflect in the name. They just happen to be 4 digits